# Changing KVM VM listening on 5901 to some other port

Tags: linux-networking, kvm-virtualization, qemu, tightvnc

OK this is rather silly, but real problem.

`vncserver` keeps binding on 5902 port. That is because `qemu` is listening on 5900 and 5901:

```
% netstat -lntup 
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5900          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1090/qemu-system-x8 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5901          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1137/qemu-system-x8 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5902            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7163/Xtightvnc      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6002            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7163/Xtightvnc
```

I suspect this has to do with me setting display to VNC in VM configurations. Believe it or not, otherwise the keyboard in VM's console does not work (at least before actual OS boot commences). Found it on Stack, it's real.

So the question is can I change VNC port that VMs are listening on? Otherwise `Xtightvnc` always gets sets desktop to `examplehost:2` which gets in the way of my other scripts.

I run these VMs with `virt-manager`.

Comment: Certainly possible, Qemu has the command line parameter that sets the port, or even allows its VNC server to listen on an unix domain socket (useful to secure access via SSH). Exactly how do you run these Qemu processes?

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov I just created VMs on a new host using `virt-manager`. Then, as I wrote, set display to VNC. That's it. And now they listen on 5901+ ports. P.S. I've done this on Bookworm host. A bug?

Comment: That's normal default behaviour. Why suspecting "bug" in the first place, did you read something in the manual and observed it worked in some undocumented way? Also, as this information is essential, I put it into the question for you. Next time do it yourself (from the very beginning), please.

Answer (score 1):

This technology is called [libvirt](https://libvirt.org/), and virt-manager you mentioned is just one of its clients.

That's normal default behaviour. Let's look [at the documentation](https://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#graphical-framebuffers):

> ```
> ...
> <devices>
>   ...
>   <graphics type='vnc' port='5904' sharePolicy='allow-exclusive'>
>     <listen type='address' address='1.2.3.4'/>
>   </graphics>
>   <graphics type='rdp' autoport='yes' multiUser='yes' />
>   ...
> </devices>
> ...
> ```
>
> ...
>
> `vnc`
>
> Starts a VNC server. The `port` attribute specifies the TCP port number (with -1 as legacy syntax indicating that it should be auto-allocated). The `autoport` attribute is the new preferred syntax for indicating auto-allocation of the TCP port to use. The `passwd` attribute provides a VNC password in clear text. If the `passwd` attribute is set to an empty string, then VNC access is disabled. The `keymap` attribute specifies the keymap to use. It is possible to set a limit on the validity of the password by giving a timestamp `passwdValidTo='2010-04-09T15:51:00'` assumed to be in UTC. The `connected` attribute allows control of connected client during password changes. VNC accepts keep value only *since 0.9.3*. NB, this may not be supported by all hypervisors.

So, if `autoport` feature is used (the default with `virt-manager`), when VM starts it gets assigned first available port starting with 5900: first one gets 5900, next 5901, etc. If you start them in a different order, they "swap" ports. If you bind it to some port, it will try to use that port, and if it's busy, the VM won't start.

I don't know whether t's possible to change the port using `virt-manager`, but it's not the only libvirt control client available. Using [`virsh`](https://download.libvirt.org/virshcmdref/html-single/) you can directly edit the VM definition in XML format. On the server:

```
virsh list -all
virsh edit <name>
```

First command lists all your VMs, second one will will open a default editor (probably, `vi`; you can set `EDITOR` environment variable to use something else, for example try running `EDITOR=nano virsh edit <name>`). After save and editor quit you need to **stop and then start** the VM for changes to take effect; the **restart is not sufficient as it doesn't restart the Qemu process**:

```
virsh shutdown <name>
virsh start <name>
```

(or from virt-manager GUI).

It should bind on the specified port only. Also it's possible to make it listen to the unix domain socket; read the linked libvirt documentation page further to learn, how. This will have the benefit of using the file name so to guarantee there will be nothing occupying the binding space for the VNC server. I never tried it myself (didn't use libvirt for 10+ years) and I don't know if virt-manager is able to connect to a socket.